# filter in treeview for multiple columns data filter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, treeview

sir i am new in python

i downloaded the code from the web

see the code

that run okay without any problem

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

inp = [{'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '100', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'GBR', 'Volume': '200', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'CAD', 'Volume': '300', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '400', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '100', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'GBR', 'Volume': '200', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'CAD', 'Volume': '300', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '400', 'Country': 'DK'},
       ]
class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Volume")

        combofr = Frame(self)
        combofr.pack(expand=True, fill=X)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, show='headings')
        columns = list(inp[0].keys())

        self.filters = []

for cols in columns:
            name = 'combo_' + col
            self.filters.append(name)
setattr(self, name, ttk.Combobox(combofr, values=[''] + sorted(set(x[col] for x in inp)), state="readonly"))
            getattr(self, name).pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=X)
            getattr(self, name).bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.select_from_filters)

        self.tree["columns"] = columns
        self.tree.pack(expand=TRUE, fill=BOTH)

for i in columns:
            self.tree.column(i, anchor="w")
            self.tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor="w")

for i, row in enumerate(inp):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text=i, values=list(row.values()))

def select_from_filters(self, event=None):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

        all_filter = lambda x: all(x[f.split('_')[-1]] == getattr(self, f).get() or getattr(self, f).get() == '' for f in self.filters)
for row in inp:
            if all_filter(row):
                self.tree.insert("", "end", values=list(row.values()))

root = Application()
root.mainloop()
```

how do I use this df in this code?

```
df=pd.read_csv('d://data.csv')
```

Now that the code used has the list, I want to use a Pandas dataframe.

```
inp = [{'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '100', 'Country': 'SE'},
      {'Currency': 'GBR', 'Volume': '200', 'Country': 'SE'},
        columns = list(inp[0].keys())
```

please give me idea how to use the pandas data frames in this code

for multicolumn data filter

the code download link

I am waiting for your valuable reply

Comment: It is hard to help you as your question is quite vague and we don't know what's the data structure in the .csv file. I would suggest you get familiar with pandas dataframe by playing around with small amount of data, you can then figure out how to put the data from the dataframe into a treeview. Also, please fix the indentation of your code. As an alternative, you might want to check out [pandastable](https://pypi.org/project/pandastable/).

Comment: this is my csv file data and column name 
CURRENCY DATE TIME VOLUME
EUR / USD 2020-01-08 04:31 200
EUR / USD 2020-01-08 04:32 300
EUR / USD 2020-01-08 04:33 400
EUR / USD 2020-01-08 04:34 500
EUR / USD 2020-01-08 04:35 600
EUR / USD 2020-01-08 04:36 700
EUR / USD 2020-01-08 04:37 800
EUR / USD 2020-01-08 04:38 900
EUR / GBP 2020-01-08 04:39 1000
EUR / GBP 2020-01-08 04:40 110
EUR / GBP 2020-01-08 04:41 1200
EUR / GBP 2020-01-08 04:42 1300
EUR / GBP 2020-01-08 04:43 1400
EUR / GBP 2020-01-08 04:44 1500
EUR / GBP 2020-01-08 04:45 1600
EUR / GBP 2020-01-08 04:46 1700

Comment: CURRENCY DATE TIME VOLUME

Comment: column name ===   CURRENCY DATE TIME VOLUME

Comment: You might want to understand what classes in Python are: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html